# Getting â€™ encoding errors with NRECO Html to Pdf

Tags: c#, html

I am using the NReco Html to Pdf conversion dll for C# but it's failing to encode correctly. The html is rendering properly but when i render the pdf, it fails to convert the ' or " characters correctly which i know is encoding. Looking for someone who has used this dll and solved this issue, below is my encoding meta for the html page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" charset="UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The meta command is wrong. It should be either

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

or

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

(with no http-equiv).

Note, however, that using a meta command for the charset is no guarantee that the desired charset is indeed used. The actual http header may override this setting with a charset of its own.

Also, with regards to your comment that it's rendered correctly, note that web browsers may use a different algorithm to determine the encoding than the dll. Correcting the meta command may or may not help.

Comment: i'll give these a shot and see if it helps!

Comment: it worked and for those using this dll. Make sure you are selecting the entire document for the pdf generation so it includes the encoding mentioned above.

Comment: @Dinesh.net Need some more info here. Is your question also about NReco's HTML-to-PDF Generator for .NET?  If not, it might help to ask a whole new question, with all the information needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the required data is coming from database, please verify the special characters properly. This issue got resolved for me when I did change in the below places:

from **’S to 'S** and from **– to -**